# How can i open a child window in Chrome when we click the custom formula link in IE

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am having a Proposal Builder Custom Formula(TEXT) using hyperlink on opportunity. When i click that i am trying to open a VF page in new window.

Hi, i need help on this salesforce task plzz.

My requirement is..

I opened Opportunity In IE and when i click Proposal Builder link on Opp, then that VF page should open in CHROME.

Any Suggestions or ideas plzzz..

Here is the Formula field i created:
HYPERLINK("https://mysalesforceorg.com/apex/cpq?opportunity_id="& Id &"&quote_id="& Id &"&Session_id="&$Api.Session_ID,"Proposal Builder","_blank")

CPQ is the VF Page to be opened when clicked.

Thankyou...

Comment: Thankyou JCD. I found an article related to this requirement. http://www.askvg.com/force-microsoft-internet-explorer-to-always-use-google-chrome-frame-to-open-urls/.

Comment: But Google Chrome Frame for IE seems to be retired as of Jan 2014 and could not help me out. Does any one have any idea on LEGACY BROWSER SUPPORT(https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en&ref_topic=3062034)? Can this be helpful for me to acheive my task of opening a salesforce child windpow in CHROME? Any Suggestions PLZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force a browser to pass a URL to a different browser. It would be possible to create shortcuts on your desktop to open certain bookmarks in a specific browser, but what you are asking for is not possible. Once you're operating in a browser, it's going to handle any links/redirects/actions within itself (whether that be in the current tab, in a new tab, or in a new window).

With that said, there are certain extensions for Chrome that would allow an end user to render a page using an IE tab within Chrome...but there's no way for you as the developer to guarantee your users are going to do that.